# Add SFML (third party library) to C++ project on Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, sfml

I'm learning how to build a simple UI in `C++` on my Mac (OS 11.6) using `Xcode`.
As first step I'm compiling the "Hello world" program, my problem is that the build on Xcode fails but write my own command from terminal, instead, works.

This is the program, I'm using `SFML` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I have no error here but when launching `Run` from Xcode this is the output, in `Graphics.hpp` file :

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>.  //'SFML/Window.hpp' file not found
#include <SFML/Graphics/BlendMode.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/CircleShape.hpp
//other header files
```

This is how the project is structured ("TestGui" is the project name) :

```
-TestGui.xcodeproj
-TestGui(folder)
--SFML(directory with all headers file available
-- main.cpp
```

SFML source code [here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/)

So I tried to compile it with my own hands from terminal with :

```
g++ main.cpp -I ./SFML -o main
```

and

```
clang++ main.cpp -I ./SFML -o main
```

In both cases it compiled, also run worked.

Since the error is linked to a `file not found` I tried to tell it where libraries are located, so in Xcode from `Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme->Run->Arguments->Arguments passed on launch` : added `-I ./SFML`. But the error is still alive.

Added SFML folder to targets from Xcode, didn't copy-pasted but maybe I did it wrong, this is my first time.

EDIT : SFML folder:

```
--SFML
--- many .hpp files
--- 5 folders (Audio, Graphic, Network, System and Window)
```

I tried to add also this argument : `-L ./SFML` but nothing.

Comment: Is there a SFML/SFML folder? I mean it will look in the SFML folder if there is a `./SFML/Window.hpp` file relative to that folder.

Comment: You are also not linking to the SFML libraries. Once you get past the include path problem you should expect linker errors.

Comment: @drescherjm I will edit the post, give me a second

Comment: @drescherjm Edited by the way no there isn't, and do you have any suggestion on what I could do to link SFML libraries?

Comment: Have you tried to follow their tutorial https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-osx.php?

Comment: @Asperi Yes I did it on an other project, there is also a video on YouTube with same steps of official docs but I got this error : dyld: Library not loaded: Reason: no suitable image found . not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.

Comment: Solved, I don't know which god helped me I think I will thanks Thor